# Вывод в две колонки из одной колонки другой таблицы Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

у меня появилась проблема. У меня есть база данных по футболу в ней есть таблица команд и таблица матчей.
У меня есть связь что в таблицу матчей выводится в 2 колонки id команд которые играли и берутся они с таблицы команд соответственно.

Как мне вывести так, чтобы вместо id были названия команд? Пробовал так:

```
select 
  id_match, match_result, teams_name, id_team2, stadion_name, match_date
from 
  nebera_match, nebera_teams, nebera_stadion 
where 
  nebera_match.id_stadion=nebera_stadion.id_stadion  and
  nebera_match.id_team1=nebera_teams.id_teams  
order by id_match;
```

Здесь заменяю id на названия где нужно кроме второй команды, а когда прописываю и вторую

```
select 
  id_match, match_result, teams_name, teams_name, stadion_name, match_date 
from 
  nebera_match, nebera_teams, nebera_stadion 
where 
  nebera_match.id_stadion=nebera_stadion.id_stadion  and
  nebera_match.id_team1=nebera_teams.id_teams  and
  nebera_match.id_team2=nebera_teams.id_teams
order by id_match;
```

то появляется пустая таблица

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя получить сразу две команды из таблицы `nebera_teams` для одной записи в таблице `nebera_match`. Более подробно см. в [ответе от @Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932524).

Не стоит пользоваться т.н. старым синтаксисом (*Old Style Oracle syntax*) соединения таблиц с условием соединения в `WHERE`. Он не входит в стандарт SQL, менее гибкий, трудночитаем и больше не рекомендуется к использованию.

Правильно надо так:

```sql
SELECT id_match, match_result, t1.teams_name, t2.teams_name, stadion_name, match_date 
  FROM nebera_match m
  JOIN nebera_stadion s on s.id_stadion = m.id_stadion
  JOIN nebera_teams t1 on t1.id_teams = m.id_team1
  JOIN nebera_teams t2 on t2.id_teams = m.id_team2 
 ORDER BY id_match;
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `nebera_teams.id_teams` не может одновременно равняться `nebera_match.id_team1` и `nebera_match.id_team2` (если команда не играет сама с собой). Используйте два `JOIN`-а таблиц `nebera_teams` и `nebera_match` с разными `alias`-ами.

Comment: По видимому ТС просто взял предложеное решение, которое полностью правильное, и опубликовал с ним свой ответ, вместо того, чтобы поблагодарить. Бывает же ))

Answer (score 0):

Решено так:

```
SELECT id_match, match_result, t1.teams_name, t2.teams_name, stadion_name, match_date 
  FROM nebera_match, nebera_teams t1, nebera_teams t2, nebera_stadion 
 WHERE nebera_match.id_stadion=nebera_stadion.id_stadion
   AND nebera_match.id_team1=t1.id_teams
   AND nebera_match.id_team2=t2.id_teams
 ORDER BY id_match;
```